# button layout issue in IE8

Tags: css

my search which is on the right side has a button named as Go, it is on right place in all modern browsers except IE8 (in IE7 and IE6 it is a nightmare but I don't care for those browsers).
I tried a few things but the button is not coming to its place in IE8 can someone tell me why is it so 
here is an image to show what I mean
http://content.screencast.com/users/cryoffalcon/folders/Jing/media/92fc0c87-44ac-4c7a-9af5-d8d5824ef85d/go%20button.png

Here is the demo page http://bloghutsbeta.blogspot.com/2012/03/testing-3.html
and if you don't want to look for the css 
here is the css:

```
.formbox {
background:#434445;
border-top-color:#0f0f0f;
border-top-style:solid;
border-top-width:3px;
border-left-color:#0f0f0f;
border-left-style:solid;
border-left-width:3px;
border-right-color:#797d7d;
border-right-style:solid;
border-right-width:3px;
border-bottom-color:#797d7d;
border-bottom-style:solid;
border-bottom-width:3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
color:#787D7D;
font:13px Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
margin: 3px 0 5px 5px;
padding:1px;
}
.formbutton {
margin:0 5px 5px 0;
color:#B6E85E;
text-shadow: 0 0 4px #7F241C, 0 0 4px #7F241C,
        0 0 4px #7F241C;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the top and bottom margins from `.formbox` and `.formbutton`, and setting them both to `vertical-align: top;` largely sorted the problem in IE8. If you need that vertical space around them, you could move use `padding` on the parent `form` (and make it `display: block;`).

(Using [conditional classes](http://lostmonocle.com/post/108304549/css-tip-conditional-classes) makes it a lot easier to target IE-specific fixes like these)

Answer (score 2):

This is easily fixed if you create a conditional statement in your html head to wrap your new stylesheet in such as

```
<!--[if IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/ie.css" /><![endif]-->
```

and put the following CSS into your stylesheet this should fix the problem.

```
input.formbutton.buttonbloghuts.buttongradient {
position: relative;
top: 8px;
}
```

You already have a conditional statement in your head to create your HTML5 elements.

Any problems and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: I like your method too, it is also as useful as the other one, I just chose one of the methods, no hard feeling, thanks a lot for your help I really appreciate that.

Comment: No problem at all. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide a jsfiddle of the button code that would help. IE dev tools aren't cooperating very will with me. If my memory serves, try adding float left on both input fields and see what happens.

Look at this site and at the search: it's really similar done but there's an extra div to do stretchy stuff : [http://www.genesismedicalimaging.com](http://www.genesismedicalimaging.com/)

Comment: I am in afghanistan with 5KBps speed don't expect me to use jsfiddle :P

Comment: Is jsFiddle really that bandwidth-intensive?